# Passing Viewbag Data from Controller to Partial View Returns Null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, partial-views, viewbag

I am having issues passing Viewbag data from my controller action to my partial view.  It keeps on returning null and I'm struggling to understand why.  I have gone through about every article on using Viewbag and my code seems to be correct.

**My Controller Action:**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult _FileList(int id)
    {
        ClaimViewModel claim = new ClaimViewModel();
        claim.document = _documentService.GetDocument(session.customerId, id);

        string filePath = _fileService.ViewFile("azureContainer", claim.document.DocumentPath);

        ViewBag.file = filePath;

        return PartialView("_FileList");
    }
```

**My Main View:**

```
@Html.Partial("_FileList", Model.Documents)
```

**My Partial View (_FileList.cshtml):**

```
<div class="list-group">
        @foreach (var file in Model)
        {
            <button type="button" id="docsButton" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#docsModal" 
                    onclick="_viewer.OpenUrl('@ViewContext.ViewBag.file'); return false;">
                @file.Name           
            </button>
        }
    </div>
```

The ViewBag is supposed to store a string to a URL to a specific file, but in the partial view it returns null.  I've tried different workarounds, such as adding in `new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "file", ViewBag.file } }` to my call to the partial view in my main view, but I haven't been able to get anything to work.  I know my `filePath` in my controller is not null.  I've tested that to make sure.  So, I'm not entirely sure what is going wrong here and was wondering if someone could help me out.  I've already checked out the different threads on this site about the issue, but none of the solutions have been helpful.  I need to have `Model.Documents` in my `@Html.Partial` because I need to reference a completely separate model as well.  Does anyone understand what might be going on here?  I feel like I'm misunderstanding something either within my controller or my partial view.

**Note:**
I am using Atalasoft's Web Document Viewer, which is where the `_viewer.OpenUrl()` comes from.

Comment: `@Html.Partial(....)` does not call your `_FileList` method (it just renders the `_FileList.cshtml` partial based on your `Documents` property). To call the the method and return its partial, you need `@Html.Action(...)`

Comment: e.g. `@Html.Action("__FileList", new { id = ?? })` but that would not render ant documents since you not passing a model to the partial in the method, so not really clear what you wanting to generate

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, @Html.Action was taken out of Asp.Net Core.  That is what I'm currently using.  Basically, the partial view is a Bootstrap modal that opens up and displays the document viewer which then opens up the designated document.  I need the model for the documents to be passed to it so then I may access the given documents in the partial view.  But I also need my Viewbag to carry over which holds the URL to the document that is being opened up.  It's kind of convoluted, I know.